# Late registration of services with asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a Web API implementation in ASP.NET Core and I'd like to use the included Dependency Injection.
In addition I have late binded assemblies, where I have to load a Type and create an instance of it, which can have dependencies to the main application.

I am trying to load dynamic resources from Assemblies I do not know while startup. So I am using `Assembly.Load("name")` and look up factory types, that give me the resource reader implementation of the Assembly.
So I know the type I need to create an instance of, but I cannot register it to the IServiceCollection and therefore cannot create instances with the ServiceProvider.

So I tried to register my found types to the IServiceCollection which was provided by the framework. For what I registered the ServiceCollection within itself.

```cs
// Within Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollection>(services);
}

// A service to register new dependencies later on
public class ServiceRegistrationService : IServiceRegistrationService
{    
  public IServiceCollection Services { get; }
  public IServiceRegistrationService RegisterSelfTransient(Type type)
  {
    Services.AddTransient(type);
    return this;
  }
}
```

After calling this method like:

```cs
ServiceRegistrationService.RegisterSelfTransient(typeof(MyConcreteType));
```

I'd expect the IServiceProvider to resolve a new instance of my type.
Is there a way to register services after leaving the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method?

Comment: Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am not sure this how dependency in injection should be used.  Because assembly resolution and dependency injection are two separate concepts.   You dependency injection just maps instances of concrete classes to abstractions.  For example you could use an interface and class that implements that interface.  This has nothing to do on how you resolve the assembly containing such types.  The resolution of the assembly must happen before the first instantiation of a type contained in it.  I for example load the assembles at the entry point Program.cs

Comment: So I resolve the assemblies before the Startup.cs class gets executed... By handling the AssemblyResolve event.  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;  This way by the time I register my dependencies my assemblies have already been resolved or at least are ready to be resolved by the mentioned event handler.

Comment: Do you have the source code to the other assemblies you are loading?  Are you compiling and building them too?  Or are they third-party?

Comment: The libs are built by myself. My classes are readers wich should be dynamically  executed. They are not referenced in the executable project, because the deploment should work even if some of the worker libs are not installed. See it as extensibility point or plugin interface. Why I want to use DI? I want the plugins to have access to implementations of the main application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After execution of WebApplicationBuilder.Build() in Program.cs's top-level statements, the IServiceCollection turns to read-only one:

```
public IHost Build()
{
   ...
   // Prevent further modification of the service collection now that the provider is built.
   _serviceCollection.MakeReadOnly();
   ...
}
```

So it seems no further changes could be introduced after that.